# Unable to see new savings on dev URL in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

If I navigate to dev URL, I can't see the last changes I saved, until I perform a deployment. How can I fix this?
I would like to see my last saved changes, when I go to dev, even without having to deploy.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the updates on your Web App using apps script without having to make New deployments everytime, you can use the Test Deployment option:

[image]

The changes you make after saving will reflect instantly by going to the Test deployment URL:[image]

Or you can keep the tab open and just refresh it.

[image]